# Travel guide Yaounde-Cameroon to Goma -Congo (land only )

Tags: visas, transit, public-transport, hotels, borders

I will like to make a trip from Yaounde Cameroon to Goma-Congo via land only no ferry or river. Please if any one have a guide please help. I'm a Cameroonian with Cameroon passport